# BeautifulSoup downloading corrupt pdfs

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have some code that downloads pdf files from a website but when I download the pdf files they are all corrupted, the pdfs appear to contain no data when I examine them in a hex editor. Any idea why?

EDIT - I have found that if I click on the link to the pdf it will load but if I attempt to open in a new tab or paste the url into a new tab it will give a blank output. The link has some javascript

```
onclick="var win = window.open(this.href,'','');return false;"
```

**Code**

```
pdf_links = []
box_2 = right_div.find_all("div", {"class":"right"})[2]#Contains PDF links
for link in box_2.find_all('a'):
  current_link = link.get('href')
  if current_link.endswith('pdf'):
     pdf_links.append('http://' + set_domain + current_link)

for url in pdf_links:  
    response = requests.get(url)   
    with open(join('C:/Users/Ninja2k/Desktop', basename(url)), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Within context manager, do close the file using `f.close()`

```
for url in pdf_links:  
    response = requests.get(url)   
    with open(join('C:/Users/Ninja2k/Desktop', basename(url)), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Could you please give the url for the website? It would be good to reproduce the issue and solve for it.

Comment: Pruthvi Kumar,I'm afraid I can't but the code above works on other websites. I have tried with urlib also and it gives blank output too. The pdf opens fine if I click it but not if I attempt to follow its url directly.